# Solving a trigonometric equation without graph

Tags: trigonometry

I want the solution to cosx = x. I don't have any idea how to proceed. For instance if I want to compare angle x with angle y which satisfies tan y = cosy. How do I proceed? I am not willing to use graphs or calculators.

Can taylor series be used to solve cosx = x as cos x = 1 - x^2/2 (approx.). Can someone help me out with an intuitive solution?

Comment: One way to do this is through numerical methods. The Taylor series perhaps will help, but may be quite difficult to make use of

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Newton's method is good enough in this case. The taylor-polynomials do not make the solution easier since for a good approximation you need a polynomial equation with high degree and moreover, you have to check which of the roots satisfy the given equation. In short, you have no choice, numerical methods is all you can apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall give you a $\color{red}{\large 1400}$ years old *approximation*.

$$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad \text{for} \qquad -\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2$$ So, solving $x=\cos(x)$ reduces the problem of finding the solution of the cubic equation
$$x^3+4 x^2+\pi ^2 x-\pi ^2=0$$ The discriminant
$$\Delta=256 \pi ^2-83 \pi ^4-4 \pi ^6 $$ being negative, there is one real root.

Using the hyperbolic method, the solution is given by
$$x=-\frac{2}{3} \left(2+\sqrt{3 \pi ^2-16} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{128-63 \pi ^2}{2 \left(3 \pi
   ^2-16\right)^{3/2}}\right)\right)\right)=0.738305\cdots$$ while the exact solution (the Dottie number) is $0.739085\cdots$. That is to say that we face a $0.1$% relative error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact way to solve this equation, you can try transcendental approaches. For instance:

Writing $f(x)=\cos x−x\, \implies\, f'(x)=-\sin x-1$

Newton's Method states that $x_{\text{n+1}} = x_{\text{n}} - \dfrac{f(x_{\text{n}})}{f'(x_{\text{n}})}$

Starting with $x_{\text{0}}=1$ and repeat until you see some sort of numerical convergence. I usually go with at least $10$ decimal places, as rounding up or down affects the convergence.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to do this one is by iteration.  Start with some guess for $x$, say $x_1=\frac12$ and compute $x_2=\cos x$.  If $x_2$ is close enough to $x1$, take it as the solution.  Otherwise, take $x_2$ as the new value of $x_1$ and do it again.  Repeat until done.

```
from math import cos

x1 = .5
x2 = cos(x1)
epsilon = .00001
while abs(x1-x2)> epsilon:
    x1 = x2
    x2 = cos(x1)
print(x1)
```

This prints  $0.739090063988251$